# "gen_id()" ou "select max()" para Auto Incremento em um campo PK?

Tags: firebird, trigger

Atualmente utilizo um *Trigger* com este código SQL para obter um Auto Incremento a ser atribuído no campo com chave primária (**PK**) das tabelas:

```
create or alter trigger TRI_CLIENTES_BI for CLIENTES
active before insert position 0
as
begin
  if (new.ID is null) then -- linha 1
    select coalesce(max(ID),0)+1 from CLIENTES into new.ID; -- linha 2
end
```

O que a "linha 2" faz é pegar o último "ID" incrementando 1 e atribuir à "new.ID" caso "new.ID" esteja nulo antes de inserir o registro. Eu vejo muitos exemplos utilizando outro método na "linha 2" que é o seguinte:

```
...
    new.ID = gen_id(GEN_CLIENTES,1);
...
```

Neste caso, o "new.ID" está recebendo o valor do *Generator* incrementando 1.

Acredito que o primeiro método deixa o código mais enxuto e de melhor manutenção, já evitando criar um *Generator* para cada tabela e ter que resetar cada um quando necessário.

O primeiro método pode causar algum tipo de conflito quando houver muitas transações simultâneas? O segundo método seria mais adequado e de melhor performance por não utilizar `select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É sempre recomendado utilizar generators ou sequences para obter valores auto incrementáveis, pois fica a cargo do SGBD gerenciar as concorrências de transações, o que garante muito mais confiabilidade e consistência nos dados.

E este tipo de auto incremento é sempre menos custoso para o SGDB do que um select em uma tabela.